# Fail to "play new" on Mac

Tags: java, macos, playframework, playframework-2.0

I run into an exception whenever trying play run on my Mac.

Detail stack track is as 
    The new application will be created in /Users/admin/mine/test2

```
What is the application name? 
> test2    

Which template do you want to use for this new application? 

1 - Create a simple Scala application
2 - Create a simple Java application
3 - Create an empty project

> 2

java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.reflect.ClassManifest$class.newArray(ClassManifest.scala:113)
at scala.reflect.ClassTypeManifest.newArray(ClassManifest.scala:233)
at scala.reflect.ClassManifest$class.newWrappedArray(ClassManifest.scala:133)
at scala.reflect.ClassTypeManifest.newWrappedArray(ClassManifest.scala:233)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArrayBuilder.mkArray(WrappedArrayBuilder.scala:31)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArrayBuilder.resize(WrappedArrayBuilder.scala:37)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArrayBuilder.ensureSize(WrappedArrayBuilder.scala:49)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArrayBuilder.$plus$eq(WrappedArrayBuilder.scala:54)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArrayBuilder.$plus$eq(WrappedArrayBuilder.scala:24)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:213)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:34)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:33)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:212)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.filter(WrappedArray.scala:33)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterNot(TraversableLike.scala:223)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.filterNot(WrappedArray.scala:33)
at scalax.file.FileSystem.fromSeq(FileSystem.scala:97)
at scalax.file.FileSystem.apply(FileSystem.scala:108)
at scalax.file.FileSystem.presentWorkingDirectory(FileSystem.scala:48)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultFileSystem.doCreateFromSeq(DefaultFileSystem.scala:26)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultFileSystem.doCreateFromSeq(DefaultFileSystem.scala:20)
at scalax.file.FileSystem.fromString(FileSystem.scala:90)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultPath.toAbsolute(DefaultPath.scala:40)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultPath.toAbsolute(DefaultPath.scala:36)
at scalax.file.FileSystem.presentWorkingDirectory(FileSystem.scala:48)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultFileSystem.doCreateFromSeq(DefaultFileSystem.scala:26)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultFileSystem.doCreateFromSeq(DefaultFileSystem.scala:20)
at scalax.file.FileSystem.fromString(FileSystem.scala:90)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultPath.toAbsolute(DefaultPath.scala:40)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultPath.toAbsolute(DefaultPath.scala:36)
at scalax.file.FileSystem.presentWorkingDirectory(FileSystem.scala:48)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultFileSystem.doCreateFromSeq(DefaultFileSystem.scala:26)
at scalax.file.defaultfs.DefaultFileSystem.doCreateFromSeq(DefaultFileSystem.scala:20)
....
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Java version is OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-internal-henri_2011_06_08_08_48-b00)
Scala version is 2.9.1 (install via brew)
Sbt version is 0.11.3
Playframework version is 2.0.4 (same problem with 2.10 actually)

What should I do then?

Comment: Have the user right to write in this directory ?

Comment: I created it inside /Users/[my account] and to make sure read/ write permission, I added chmod -R 777 to that folder. So, I guess, the rights are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is because of java version. You should try another java version. I use java version "1.6.0_37" on my mac.

Comment: It seems to be JDK 7 problem on Mac as I run it normally on my Windows machine. Thanks for a help

Comment: Just a note if someone want to swap java version on Mac. Just key in ``export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home` -v 1.6``